# How to start select2 script with initial search value

Tags: jquery

I am using select2. I would like on page load to set the initial search/filter. Can anyone help please? This is my code:

```
<select name="productid" id="productid" class="search_product" autocomplete="off" style="max-width:450px" required>
                <option></option>
                ';
                while($list = $sql->fetch()) {

                    echo '
                    <option value="'.$list['id'].';'.$list['stock'].'">'.$list['item'].'</option>
                    ';
                }

                echo '
                </select>
```

I want to set the initial search value? It is not working. I have tried:

```
 <script>
            $(function() { 
                $('input.select2-search__field').attr("val","NS/NR"); 

           });
        </script>
        ';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can't set value in a `<select>` element because unlike `<input>` it takes the
  selected value from the `<option>`, so you'll have to create an element
  and then append it.
- A good idea, however, would be to give the value to the first empty
  `<option>` you defined and make it `selected`.
- And if the value you're selecting is coming from `database` you
  should check the condition and make it `selected`.

I've created a demo which works for me, see if it works for you as well.

```js
$(function() {
    let $html = `<option value='NS/NR' selected>NS/NR</option>`
    
    $('.search_product').select2();
    $('.search_product').append($html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select name="productid" id="productid" class="search_product" autocomplete="off" style="max-width:450px" required>
  <option></option>
  <option value='AAA/BBB'>AAA/BBB</option>
  <option value='CCC/DDD'>CCC/DDD</option>
  <option value='EEE/FFF'>EEE/FFF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is good idea however if I have three products all starting with AAB for example then it won't work if I want to filter on those products. I think I just have to apply a database filter first.